# If API value is empty show default value

Tags: php

I want this to display `0` if the `nb_impressions` is empty

```
foreach ($content as $row) {
   $impressions = $row['nb_impressions'];
   print("<td'>$impressions</td>");
}
```

The value is from a `HTTP API` however, if the value is empty it displays as empty, how can I give these empty values `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ternary operator to check as

`(isset($row['nb_impressions']) && $row['nb_impressions'])` and set default `0`

```
foreach ($content as $row) {
    $impressions = (isset($row['nb_impressions']) && $row['nb_impressions']) ? $row['nb_impressions'] : 0;
    print("<td'>$impressions</td>");
}
```

After your comment, you can combine this into a function for checking

```
function isExist($var,$default=''){
    if (isset($var) && $var) {
        return $var;
    }
    return $default;
}
```

And use like this

```
$impressions = isExist($row['nb_impressions'], 0);
$clicks= isExist($row['nb_clicks'], 0);
$visits = isExist($row['nb_visits'], 0);
```

Comment: You can just do this:

    $impressions = @$row['nb_impressions'] ?: 0;

The ?: is ternary shorthand for "if this evaluates true, use it, else..." and we suppress the initial error because we know it might be empty, and in that case just use the 0.

Comment: Thank you, this does work and I had tried it previously. Unfortunately, when I add the same to multiple it breaks. For example, I also have `$clicks` and `$visits`. Do you know a way that I can make this work for all?

Comment: Yeah, you can use ternary operators :) Its might be helpful for you :)

Comment: @sorak : I thought we should not use `@` until it is very much clear to us that `it excludes errors and warnings`, in development mode we should not use this `@`

Comment: @Darren dou you want to check same time both of `$clicks` and `$visits` ? or do you just want one of them ?

Comment: I only use it in that case, suppressing a specific expected and therefore unhelpful error. Null or undefined still evaluates false the uses the desired value.

Comment: @sorak this fixed my issue with multiples. Also wow, I am not too worried about the errors or warnings as this is taken care of in a previous statement. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @rufatZZ yes, the above is displaying analytics for Piwik Server and require the values to be displayed in a table. The shorthand and use of `@` seems to have fixed the issues I was having.

Comment: @Darren : Also check updated ans, I created new function `isExist()`

Comment: @wow : Thank you, that is a much nicer way than I had thought. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You just add `if` statement

```
foreach ($content as $row) {
   $impressions = $row['nb_impressions'];
   if(isset($impressions)){
       print("<td'>$impressions</td>");
   }else{
       print("<td>0</td>");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use php empty() function to check

```
foreach ($content as $row) {
   if(!empty($row['nb_impressions'])){
       $impressions = $row['nb_impressions'];
   }
   else{
       $impressions = 0;
   }
   print("<td'>$impressions</td>");
}
```

Simply straight forward.